# What tools can I use to deploy PHP code to production server?

Tags: php, deployment

So far I only know about [Capifony](http://capifony.org/), but it's mostly for Symfony.

All I need is a script to run tests, check version, package some files, send them to a server, and run some commands there.

I have heard about continuous integrations, but it looks complicated and I'm not sure that's what I need.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Capistrano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capistrano)

Despite the fact that this tool for Ruby projects, it can be used for projects in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at `r-sync`, this is what we use in my company.
You can look here fo some description : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync

Answer (score 0):

If you have shell access on the server, [scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) in batch mode might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For just deploying, (not running tests) you could use a source control system. At my company, we simply check all tested and working code into a prod branch, then log in to our production account and `sv update` that application. (We're currently using subversion for source control)